# jQueryUI draggable not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$(function() {
  $("#hello").draggable();
})
```

```css
#hello {
  width: 10vw'
 height:10vh;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="hello"></div>
```

This is my code.  Why isn't draggable working? I'm pretty sure everything is right; this should've been pretty simple stuff but what have I done wrong? The id is right, the div is right, I have no clue as to what's wrong.

Comment: There's a stray `'` but no `;` after `10vw`

Comment: only fix what @ChrisG mentioned, and your code works fine

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you must apply class = "ui-widget-content" for your element and do what ChrisG says.